# My seasonal mount armour is missing!

Tags: diablo-iv

In Diablo 4 Season 2, the third chapter of the season rewards horse armour. However when I visit the Stables I can't find it listed.

[image: Strips and Points]

Where can I find this unlocked armour and how can I apply it to my mount?

As you can see, it's not available from the Stable Master.
[image]

---

*Update*

Seems that it's not just me and could be a bug. https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/17aoibc/seasonal_journey_mount_rewards_not_being_added/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I logged in this evening I checked the Stable Master in Zarbinzet and the mount armour was there. I guess this has been fixed?

[image: Strips and Points mount armour]

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [stable master](https://maxroll.gg/d4/resources/mounts-stable-master#stable-master-&-cosmetics-header) in a town that has one Kyovashad for example. This is the place where you can choose a different mount and customize the cosmetics.

> You can customize your mount's appearance at the Stable Master in most major cities and outposts. At this NPC you can customize your mount's horse breed, Armor, Saddle, and display a Trophy from your many conquests.

Comment: Yeah, I thought someone might misunderstand the question like this. I have updated the question to show the stable master is missing the armour in question.